# find the derivative of sin x by first principle?

Tags: calculus

[I wanted to know where the h went when the limit was applied to the cos function they have used the trig fuction Sin A - Sin B, click on the link to see the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TNxVN.png)

Comment: Please type your question here, rather than making a link to a picture.

Answer (score 1):

It uses the following property : $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{sin(x)}{x} =1$.

Answer (score 1):

$$lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{sin(x)}{x} =1$$

You have to learn how to use LATEX so to help us to understand the problem and where the problem is!This link will help you https://oeis.org/wiki/List_of_LaTeX_mathematical_symbols

Answer (score 0):

There is an identity: $\lim_{x\to0}\sin(x)/x = 1$.